# get objects from an array by name at one array iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays

is there a way to get values from an array by fields at once?

for example there is an array of objects

```
const arr = [
    {
        name: 'tomato',
        value: 20,
    },
    {
        name: 'apple',
        value: 44,
    },
    {
        name: 'mango',
        value: 36,
    }
]
```

from this array I need to get all objects by name. And in a result a need 3 object. The one way is to find each object in an array by name

```
const tomato = arr.find(item => item.name === 'tomato')
const apple = arr.find(item => item.name === 'apple')
const mango = arr.find(item => item.name === 'mango')
```

is there others way how can I get object from an array by name? is it possible to do at one array iteration?

Comment: Is it always going to be tomato, apple, mango? Because then you should rather use an object.

Comment: this objects store in an array

Comment: Use a regular [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop and store them in separate variables.

Comment: I mean like that: `const fruits = {tomato: 20, apple: 44, mango: 46};` You can also map it to that form with a `reduce` on your current `arr`.

Comment: can there be duplicate `tomato` item? You just want to find the first one? So what if you use one iteration, and you give 3 names, then stop as soon as one is found for each name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `reduce()` and [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

```js
const arr = [{name:"tomato",value:20},{name:"apple",value:44},{name:"mango",value:36}];

const { tomato, apple, mango } = arr.reduce((a, i) => ({...a, [i.name]: i.value}), {})

console.log(tomato, apple, mango)
```

Comment: would it need to handle `[{name:"tomato",value:20},{name:"apple",value:44},{name:"mango",value:36}, {name:"tomato",value:10000}];`

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) collection:

```
let uniqueArr= new Map(arr.map(s=> [s.name, s]))
```

An example:

```js
const arr = [
    {
        name: 'tomato',
        value: 20,
    },
    {
        name: 'apple',
        value: 44,
    },
    {
        name: 'mango',
        value: 36,
    }
]

let uniqueArr = new Map(arr.map(s=> [s.name, s]))

console.log(uniqueArr.get('tomato'))
console.log(uniqueArr.get('apple'))
console.log(uniqueArr.get('mango'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [
    {
        name: 'tomato',
        value: 20,
    },
    {
        name: 'apple',
        value: 44,
    },
    {
        name: 'mango',
        value: 36,
    }
]

function getObjects(args){

  var output = [];
  
  args.forEach(name => {
  
    arr.forEach(elem => {

      if(name === elem.name)
        output.push(elem)

    });
     
  });

  return output;
}

var args = ['mango', 'tomato'];

var objs = getObjects(args);

objs.forEach(elem => console.log(elem));
```

How about this ?

Answer (score 0):

- `.flatMap()` on array
- Each object can be broken down further by `Object.entries()` and destructuring
- then `flatMap()` each object of array
- The final form is `[key, value]` arrays of each object.
- Any match between the given property and the current key will result in the corresponding value to be returned as a sub-array which finally returns flattened (extracted from the sub-array).
- Otherwise an empty sub-array is returned and flattened to nothing.

```js
const data = [{
  key1: "A",
  key2: 1
}, {
  key1: "B",
  key2: 2
}, {
  key1: "C",
  key2: 3
}];

const getValuesOf = (arrayOfObjects, property) => {
  return arrayOfObjects.flatMap(object => {
    return Object.entries(object).flatMap(([key, value]) => {
      return property === key ? [value] : []
    });
  });
};

console.log(getValuesOf(data, 'key1'));
console.log(getValuesOf(data, 'key2'));
```